# Pasting Dates for SQL Query in R

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to bring out the two dates on the second last line of the below code, outwith the SQL Query in R. Anyway this is possible?

```
myConn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "driver={SQL Server};server=SLSQL398_AGLIS\\SLSQL398;database=PortfolioAnalytics;trusted_connection=true")
data<- sqlFetch(myConn, "Data_Factset.FundChar", colnames = TRUE)

SQLCommand<- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT fc.[FactSet Fund Code], fc.FactsetDate,  fc.[Asset Class], fc.[Fund Manager], d.Id AS DeskID, d.[Name] AS DeskName, c.ClosingDate, m.NumericGrossPerformanceTarget, fc.[% Factor Risk], fc.[Predicted Tracking Error], fc.[Portfolio Predicted Beta], fc.[Port. Ending Active Share]    
                             FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Factset].[FundChar] fc 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Axioma.FactSetAccount fsa ON fc.FactsetAccountCode = REPLACE(fsa.Code, '_', '') 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Portfolio p ON fsa.PortfolioId = p.Id 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mandate m ON p.UnderlyingId = m.id 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.Mandate c ON p.UnderlyingId = c.id 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Desk d ON m.DeskId = d.Id
                             WHERE IncludesCash = 1 
                             AND [FactSet Fund Code] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND [Fund Manager] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND [FactSet Fund Code] <> 'TSNA_US' 
                             AND [Asset Class] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND FactsetDate IN ('20180531', '20180228')
                             ORDER BY [Predicted Tracking Error] DESC"))
```

This is my attempt however I get an unexpected symbol error:

```
d<-20180531
d2<-20180228
myConn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "driver={SQL Server};server=SLSQL398_AGLIS\\SLSQL398;database=PortfolioAnalytics;trusted_connection=true")
data<- sqlFetch(myConn, "Data_Factset.FundChar", colnames = TRUE)

SQLCommand<- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT fc.[FactSet Fund Code], fc.FactsetDate,  fc.[Asset Class], fc.[Fund Manager], d.Id AS DeskID, d.[Name] AS DeskName, c.ClosingDate, m.NumericGrossPerformanceTarget, fc.[% Factor Risk], fc.[Predicted Tracking Error], fc.[Portfolio Predicted Beta], fc.[Port. Ending Active Share]    
                               FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Factset].[FundChar] fc 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Axioma.FactSetAccount fsa ON fc.FactsetAccountCode = REPLACE(fsa.Code, '_', '') 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Portfolio p ON fsa.PortfolioId = p.Id 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mandate m ON p.UnderlyingId = m.id 
                               INNER JOIN dbo.Mandate c ON p.UnderlyingId = c.id 
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Desk d ON m.DeskId = d.Id
                               WHERE IncludesCash = 1 
                               AND [FactSet Fund Code] IS NOT NULL 
                               AND [Fund Manager] IS NOT NULL 
                               AND [FactSet Fund Code] <> 'TSNA_US' 
                               AND [Asset Class] IS NOT NULL 
                               AND FactsetDate IN ('"d"', '"d2"')
                               ORDER BY [Predicted Tracking Error] DESC"))
```

}

Comment: `bring out the two dates` ... what do you mean by this?  Does your current query have some problem you want to fix?

Comment: Please see updated question - essentially I am trying to bring the dates outwith the query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '"d"' and '"d2"' insertions are probably failing.

Try constructing the SQL query string outside the `sqlQuery()` command.

Try this:

```
   d <- "20180531"
   d2 <- "20180228"

   my_query <- paste0("SELECT fc.[FactSet Fund Code], fc.FactsetDate,  fc.[Asset Class], fc.[Fund Manager], d.Id AS DeskID, d.[Name] AS DeskName, c.ClosingDate, m.NumericGrossPerformanceTarget, fc.[% Factor Risk], fc.[Predicted Tracking Error], fc.[Portfolio Predicted Beta], fc.[Port. Ending Active Share]    
                         FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Factset].[FundChar] fc 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Axioma.FactSetAccount fsa ON fc.FactsetAccountCode = REPLACE(fsa.Code, '_', '') 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Portfolio p ON fsa.PortfolioId = p.Id 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mandate m ON p.UnderlyingId = m.id 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.Mandate c ON p.UnderlyingId = c.id 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Desk d ON m.DeskId = d.Id
                         WHERE IncludesCash = 1 
                         AND [FactSet Fund Code] IS NOT NULL 
                         AND [Fund Manager] IS NOT NULL 
                         AND [FactSet Fund Code] <> 'TSNA_US' 
                         AND [Asset Class] IS NOT NULL 
                         AND FactsetDate IN ('", d, "', '", d2, "')
                         ORDER BY [Predicted Tracking Error] DESC")

   myConn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "driver={SQL Server};server=SLSQL398_AGLIS\\SLSQL398;database=PortfolioAnalytics;trusted_connection=true")
   data <- sqlFetch(myConn, "Data_Factset.FundChar", colnames = TRUE)

   SQLCommand <- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, my_query))
```

Comment: you are a hero my friend